# DocSearch and Sphinx not working together

Tags: javascript, python, algolia

I am using Sphinx for a documentation website, and decided to integrate with Algolia's DocSearch.

In my `layout.html`, I included the following:

```
{% set css_files = css_files + ["https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/docsearch.js@2/dist/cdn/docsearch.min.css", "_static/custom.css"] %}

<!-- Algolia DocSearch Integration -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/docsearch.js@2/dist/cdn/docsearch.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> docsearch({
    apiKey: '....',
    indexName: 'myIndex',
    inputSelector: 'wy-side-nav-search input[type=text]',
    algoliaOptions: { 'facetFilters': ["version:v1.0"] },
    debug: false // Set debug to true if you want to inspect the dropdown 
  }); 
</script>
```

At this point I thought I was done, but I am heading to the development version of our docs, and I see nothing.

**Question 1:** Did I do something wrong with integrating the docs?

**Question 2:** My DocSearch Playground works fine. Is DocSearch working only on actual live websites? For example, can I not use it on development or on my development deployment?

**Question 3:** Do I need to disable the Sphinx search functionality for DocSearch to work?

Answer (score 0):

To your second question, [your website needs to be publicly available](https://community.algolia.com/docsearch/who-can-apply.html#the-checklist) to work with DocSearch:

[image]